# What should be approach?

Tags: oracle, ejb, oracle11g

Try to be more clear, I'm in lack of ideas in this problem, even it sounds like a classic.

My application is running on weblogic 10.3.3 application server, and for database I am using Oracle database 11g. My problem is that there is table in db, let's say "user.", there is column, let's say "columnA", in this table. This table is updating by some module of application.

What I want if when value of column is "abc.", then I have to show alert to console(IP). {IP can be retrieved from DB as it is configured in DB. this ip will be other linux system other than linux machine where oracle database is installed.} Updating is continuously done on my table from module of application. Please tell me from where should I start?, what should I read. I am not able to understand what should be approach. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger on the table can call UTL_HTTP to communicate with another machine (eg call a RESTful API).

The architectural questions are :

1. This will happen PRIOR to the commit so you may get false alerts if a change is rolled back
2. If you wait for a response, it will slow the system down.
3. What do you do if you get an non-standard response (eg the other server isn't available)

Comment: thanks,thanks for reply!.Please tell me "Can i approach WebServices.?" Please reply